# How to match a CONCATENATED value to values in a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2022

The database I’m working with is SQL Server 2022.

I have a table with item numbers like 1010080PC which ends with a C.
I also have items like 1010080 or 1010080P (without the C at the end) and I want to add the item 1010080PC to the last column GuaranteeItem if the item number in ItemNr does not end with a C

| MATNR | GuaranteeItem |
| --- | --- |
| 1010080 | 1010080PC |
| 1010080P | 1010080PC |
| 1010080PC | (empty) |

As item 1010080PC already ends with a C, I do not want to enter anything in the last column.

The table has around 170,000 rows and of these rows approx. 1,700 have an item that ends with a C.
I expect that around 3,400 rows have to be edited

This is what I want the result to be:

| MATNR | GuaranteeItem |
| --- | --- |
| 1010010 |  |
| 1010021 |  |
| 1010031P | 1010031PC |
| 1010031PC |  |
| 1010040 |  |
| 1010061 |  |
| 1010070 |  |
| 1010080 | 1010080PC |
| 1010080PC |  |
| 1011010 |  |
| 1011021 |  |
| 1011030 |  |
| 1017511 |  |
| 1017530 |  |
| 1017531 |  |
| 1017592 | 1017592PC |
| 1017592P | 1017592PC |
| 1017592PC |  |
| 1017611 |  |
| 1017821 |  |
| 1017941 |  |
| 1017951 |  |
| 1017961 | 1017961PC |
| 1017961P | 1017961PC |
| 1017961PC |  |
| 1017981 |  |

I’ve been fighting with this for a while but I’ve not been able to find a working solution.
What I’ve done is the following

I’ve made a TempTable with only the ItemNr that end with a ‘C’

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    prd.MARA.MATNR
    INTO prd.TempTable
FROM 
    prd.MARA
WHERE
prd.MARA.MATNR LIKE '%C'
```

Next I try to match the ItemNr + ‘%C’ to the ItemNr in the temp table. If the the ItemNr + ‘%C’ exists in the temp table then I add the ItemNr from the temp table to the column GuaranteeItem

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    prd.MARA.MATNR
    , CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(prd.MARA.MATNR, '%C') IN (SELECT prd.TempTable.MATNR FROM prd.TempTable) THEN prd.TempTable.MATNR
        WHEN prd.MARA.MATNR LIKE '%C' THEN '' 
        ELSE ''
        END AS GuaranteeItem
FROM
    prd.MARA
LEFT JOIN
    prd.TempTable ON prd.TempTable.MATNR = prd.MARA.MATNR
```

Somehow I can’t match `WHEN CONCAT(prd.MARA.MATNR, '%C') IN (SELECT prd.TempTable.MATNR FROM prd.TempTable) THEN`

Any advice to solve this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: In your results table you have lots of rows where MATNR doesn't end in C but GuaranteeItem is being left null. Can you explain what the logic is because this doesn't seem to be in line with the text of your question? Thanks

Comment: Dear NickW, if it is not in line, I have  not explain it correctly.
E.g. itemnr 1017961 and  1017961P both have a correspondent item 1017961PC with end with a C, so for both 1017961 and  1017961P the 1017961PC has to added to the last column.
Itemnr 1011010 doesn't have a itemnr wich end with a C. There is no  like 1011010C so no value is added to the last column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `EXISTS` operator within a case expression as the following:

```
SELECT MATNR,  
  CASE 
    WHEN
      EXISTS
        (
          SELECT 1 FROM tbl_name D
          WHERE D.MATNR = CONCAT(T.MATNR, 'PC') OR
                D.MATNR = CONCAT(T.MATNR, 'C')
        )
    THEN CONCAT(T.MATNR, IIF(RIGHT(T.MATNR, 1) = 'P', 'C','PC')) 
  ELSE '' END AS GuaranteeItem
FROM tbl_name T
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ApeVwjSI)

Comment: Dear Ahmed,
 thank you for your solution.
In the mean time I've come up with an other approach but yours is more elegant (I think)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MATNR, 
    IIF(RIGHT(MATNR  , 1) = 'C', 
    '' , 
    IIF(RIGHT(MATNR  , 1)='P', CONCAT(MATNR  ,'C'),CONCAT(MATNR  ,'PC'))) GuaranteeItem FROM prd.MARA
```

Comment: Dear gskarthikkn,
Your solution puts the value 1017961PC with the items 1017961 and 1017961P, which is correct.
But it also add a value 1017611PC to 1017611 while the value 1017611PC does not exists in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with an other approach which also works.

```
/* Create CTE with all MATNR that are CautieArtikel*/
WITH CautieArtikel AS (
    SELECT
        prd.MARA.MATNR AS MATNR1
    FROM 
        prd.MARA
    WHERE 
        prd.MARA.MATNR LIKE '%C'
)

/* Left join CTE by extracting the first part of the MATNRs */
SELECT
    prd.MARA.MATNR
    , CASE 
        WHEN prd.MARA.MATNR = ca.MATNR1 THEN '' ELSE COALESCE(ca.MATNR1, '')
        END AS GuaranteeItem
FROM
    prd.MARA
LEFT JOIN 
    CautieArtikel AS ca ON prd.MARA.MATNR = LEFT(ca.MATNR1, LEN(prd.MARA.MATNR))
```

After 3 days f**king around, my daughter came up with (most) of this solution.

I want to thank everyone for the quick response and the effort.